# Shadow color android studio

Tags: android, shadow, nine-patch

I have a ui design.
I should to make some xml file with custom shadow color.

I used to carbon library but it not work very well

I need to create shadow like this
[image: example image of shadow applied to UI]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show what you have done till now.

Comment: I'm still working on it. I used afew library like carbon,complexview,shadow layout but it wasn't exactly what i wanted.

Comment: I want import shadow color exactly figma file .

Comment: Now i export background shadows to png file in figma and set it to background items. It work very well.But it would be better to implement with code

Answer (score 1):

This should work for Android version 28 or higher.

In your xml layout, include this in your CardView.

```
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="<yourColor>"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="<yourColor>"
```

You can do the same in code by doing this:

```
mCardView.setOutlineAmbientShadowColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_blue));
mCardView.setOutlineSpotShadowColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colour_blue));
```

Comment: But i want it for api 21